# Removing leading \s from json response

Tags: json, node.js, postgresql

I have a nodejs app. I am retrieving data from bytea column in postgresql db and returning as part of my service's response. I see the below response. How can I get rid of the `\`s in the response. When I fetch the same data from jsonb column in postgresql db , I don't the leading `\`s.

```
\”products\": [
          {
            \”productId\”: \”82AA90280202\”,
            \”productCode\”: \“BHJKKLL\”,
            \”productName\”: “\TEST PROD\“,
            \”productQuantity\”: 1,
          }
        ]
```

Comment: Stop stringifying json strings. they are already strings.

Comment: I suspect the response is being returned as a string not as a json object

Comment: "data from bytea column" @AivanMonceller Agreed. PostgreSQL would know nothing about the JSON format.

Comment: Thanks a lot , everyone. @AivanMonceller how I can convert the string that I get from db to json object? Should I do json.parse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse` to decode the string back to an object.

If you have the encoded string as follows:

```
var s = "\"products\": [{\"productId\": \"82AA90280202\",\"productCode\": \"BHJKKLL\",\"productName\": \"TEST PROD\", \"productQuantity\": 1}]"
```

Then just do this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse("{" + s + "}")
```

`obj` will then hold the data as an object:

```
{ products:
   [ { productId: '82AA90280202',
       productCode: 'BHJKKLL',
       productName: 'TEST PROD',
       productQuantity: 1 } ] }
```

I'm assuming when you used the `“` or  `”` quote marks in your example, you really meant the straight-up quote (`"`).  I'm also assuming that you meant that this portion of your example:

```
"\TEST PROD\",
```

Is a typo and should have been this:

```
\"TEST PROD\",
```

Comment: In your code, the leading backslashes are being lost, essentially as if they weren't there to begin with. That of course is impacting the result.

Comment: well, no. If the string contains escaped quotes, you're going to have to escape the escapes to get the same result tha the OP is getting.